# Jquery- Hide div

Tags: jquery

I have a div inside form something like

```
<form>
<div>
showing some information here
</div>

<div id="idshow" style="display:none">
information here
</div>

</form>
```

i am population information inside div(idshow) on some button click event. what i want whenever i ill click outside div(idshow), it should be hide. just like i click on menu then menu is display and when i click outside menu it goes hide.
I need everything using jquery

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
  var target = $( event.target );

  // Check to see if the target is the div.
  if (!target.is( "div#idshow" )) {
    $("div#idshow").hide();
    // Prevent default event -- may not need this, try to see
    return( false );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do what you want like this:

```
$(document).click(function() {
  $("#idshow").hide();
});
$("#idshow").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

What happens here is when you click, the `click` event bubbles up all the way to `document`, if it gets there we hide the `<div>`.  When you click inside that `<div>` though, you can stop the bubble from getting up to `document` by using [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)...so the [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) doesn't fire, short and simple :)