# Jquery click on div open another div while closing others

Tags: jquery

Would someone help me modify this code of what I have below. I want when user clicks **boom1** it will show **booming1** and will hide **booming2** and vice-versa please help.

```
<div id="boom1" >click me</div>
<div id="boom2" >click me</div>
<div id="booming1" style="display:none;">show on click boom1</div>
<div id="booming2" style="display:none;">show on click boom2</div>


   $("#boom1").click(function () {
      $(".booming1").show(1000);

    });
        $("#boom2").click(function () {
      $(".booming2").show(1000);

    });
```

Comment: At least allow me to express myself here. 
[JQUERY DOC](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) -- 
[W3SCHOOLS JQuery tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp) -- Pretty duplicated: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928275/jquery-hide-div) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928275/jquery-hide-div) for example.

Comment: @ArnauOrriols thanks, but the point of this post is finding myself a good practice or standard to follow on and I'm not good at jQuery, Yet.

Comment: if I can give you an advise, stackoverflow is not the place to learn. You could start with w3schools link I've given before, it covers the basics in a very clean and organized way. I guess you are in a hurry; believe me, reading the documentations/tutorials may seem too much time, but at the end it saves you many many hours searching/asking/waiting blindly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some changes to the dom is made, we add a class `boom` to the targeted element headers and a `data-target` which contains the selector of the element to be displayed. Also we add a class `booming` to the target elements so that they can be identified.

We add a click handler to the `boom` element, inside the handler we get the target of the `boom` using the data-target and hide all targets elements of type `booming`

```
<div class="boom" data-target="#booming1" >click me</div>
<div class="boom" data-target="#booming2" >click me</div>
<div id="booming1" class="booming" style="display:none;">show on click boom1</div>
<div id="booming2" class="booming" style="display:none;">show on click boom2</div>
```

and

```
$(".boom").click(function () {
    var $target = $($(this).data('target'));
    $(".booming").not($target).hide();
    $target.show();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ArQK7/)

Comment: Thank you for this post, May you add explanation so I might understand it more better. also for others who are having the same problem.

Comment: This relies on HTML 5 `data-` attribute in order to work.  Quite frankly, I wouldn't have gone that route for something that simple.  To each their own.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple different ways to do this, but here is one that doens't require much change on your part

```
(function() {
  var $booming1,
    $booming2;

  $(function() {
    $booming1 = $("#booming1");
    $booming2 = $("#booming2");

    $("#boom1").click(function() {
      $booming1.show(1000);
      $booming2.hide()
    });
    $("#boom2").click(function() {
      $booming2.show(1000);
      $booming1.hide();
    });
  })
}(jQuery))
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to find the most common or standard way. So I may build up on it.

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach to this sort of task is to toggle a class on the divs you want to hide or show.

You JS would go something like this..

```
$('#boom1').click(function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active').hide();         
  $('#booming1').show(1000).addClass('active');

});//end boom1 click

$('#boom2').click(function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active').hide();  
  $('#booming2').addClass('active').show(1000);

});
```

Here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/VgbvF/

Answer (score 0):

Give them all the same class and manipulate them that way.  And place booming1 and booming2 inside of the click me div for easier manipulation as well.

Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="boom" id="boom1" >click me
<div id="booming1" style="display:none;">show on click boom1</div>
</div>
<div class="boom" id="boom2" >click me
<div id="booming2" style="display:none;">show on click boom2</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".boom").click(function(event) {
    $(".boom").children().hide();
    $(this).children().show();
});
```

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/P5y2G/