# Scrolling to div id, stack and after "stop" div id hiding (not smoth scrolling)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Have a script that showing some div when page scrolling to less than 1400 (<1400), if more than 1400 the div is hiding. But i need that div showing not by height (1400) rather by div id and hiding by "stop" div. Please can you help me.

```
<style>
#goSale {position:fixed;bottom:-300px;width:auto;height:auto;}
#goSale img {opacity:100;-moz-animation:blink normal 3s infinite ease-in-out;-webkit-animation:blink normal 3s infinite ease-in-out;
-ms-animation:blink normal 3s infinite ease-in-out;animation:blink normal 3s infinite ease-in-out;animation-iteration-count:5;-ms-animation-iteration-count:5;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:5;-o-animation-iteration-count:5;border:0px;width:100px;height:auto;}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() < 1400){
        $('#goSale').stop().animate({
            top: '65px'
            }, 1);
    }else{
        $('#goSale').stop().animate({
           top: '-100px'
        }, 1); } });

$('#goSale').scroll(function() {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
       scrollTop: 0
    }, 1, function() {
       $('#goSale').stop().animate({
           top: '65px'
       }, 1); }); }); });
</script>

<div id="goSale"><img src="img/pages/sale.png"></div>
```

Example: http://www.vichy.ho.ua - top right black cube and other leftside and right side "scrolling" elements, like Youtube and other...

Comment: i think you can create fiddle with this. thats will help both us and you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928275/jquery-hide-div

Comment: @plonknimbuzz... www.vichy.ho.ua-- top right black cube.

Comment: @Star... sorry but no... www.vichy.ho.ua-- top right black cube and other seemless elements

Comment: @JSnewbie... sorry but no...

Comment: Actually, the black image with the phone number is showing when the page is scrolled LESS than 1400px. Now your question *«But i need that div showing not by height (1400) rather by div id and hiding by "stop" div.»* is unclear. I can't figure out what you expect.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette that the div "black box" showing not when page scrolling 1400 but rather by div, for example, id="blackbox"... when the page scrolling to div, for example, id="stopbox" the "blackbox" is hiding

Comment: ok... So you want it to be hidden when another particular div is in view. Well, you have to know the position of that div and adapt your scrolled comparison using that number.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette... maybe you have an example

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette... something like this.. http://jsfiddle.net/jpXjH/6/ but not like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want it to be hidden when another particular div is in view. Well, you have to know the position of that div and adapt your scrolled comparison using that number.

So you have to take 3 measurements:

1. User's screen height
2. The top position of your "stop div"
3. The bottom position of your "stop div"

Then, some simple math... And compare with scrolled position.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Get some measurements
  var stopPosition = $("#stop").offset().top;
  var stopHeight = $("#stop").outerHeight();
  var displayHeight = $(window).height();


  // Scroll handler
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    // Show the fixed black image when the stop div is in view
    if($(this).scrollTop() < stopPosition-displayHeight || $(this).scrollTop() > stopPosition+stopHeight){
      $('#goSale').stop().animate({
        top: '65px'
      }, 1);

      // Else, hide it.
    }else{
      $('#goSale').stop().animate({
        top: '-1000px'
      }, 1);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#a,#b,#c{
  height:1000px;
}
#a{
  background-color:blue;
}
#b{
  background-color:orange;
}
#c{
  background-color:green;
}
#stop{
  height:300px;
  border:10px solid red;
}
#goSale{
  position:fixed;
  top:65px;
  right:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a"></div>
<div id="stop">
  
  <h1>The phone number in the black image is not shown when I'm in view.</h1>
  
</div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<img id="goSale" src="http://www.vichy.ho.ua/img/pages/sale.png">
```